# Hide hidden(dot) files in github atom editor

Tags: github, editor, atom-editor

I am very new to Github Atom editor. It always shows hidden files such as `.git`, `.sass` in the side pane.

How to hide hidden files(dot files) in atom editor's side pane.

Comment: Useful description on this at http://bit.ly/1Yxsv3E

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Edit > Preferences > Packages

In the field below "Installed Packages" type: "Tree View". This package has a few settings you can toggle, "Hide Ignored Names" is what you're looking for.

It's a really buried setting, not sure why.

You can also add it to your config:

```
'tree-view':
    'hideIgnoredNames': true
```

Comment: `Hide Ingored Names` only hides `.git` folder. Other option `Hide Vcs Ignored Files` hide all `.gitignore` files.

Comment: You'd think this first setting would automatically be applied, but it didn't appear to take effect until I added the 'tree-view' line to my config. Thanks @ccheney.

Comment: The tricky part is finding the well-hidden *hide* option:
**Atom > Preferences... > Packages > tree-view > Settings > Hide Ignored Names**

Comment: I found that tapping the "i" key (while the tree view is focused) will toggle hidden paths.

Comment: Thank you @aleclarson. Hitting "i" with tree-view focused is the quickest solution for me since my settings are frequently overwritten (or I'm accidentally pressing "i").

Answer (score 34):

1. From the menu bar go to **Edit > Preferences > Packages**  type in the filter "**tree-view**"  click on the "**Settings**" button of this package and then check the "**Hide Ignored Names**" choice.
2. Now go to **Edit > Preferences > Core** . In the **Ignored Names** box enter `.*` this will hide all the files/folders which are usually hidden in other file explorers.

If you want to hide normal files/folders just add them to this box separated by a Comma `,` for example : `.*, Videos, Music`

Comment: This is the right answer, because explains how to config Atom to ignore all the files you want to be ignored, not just the *.git* folder that is ignored by default.

Answer (score 28):

You can configure Atom to ignore specific files by customizing the "Ignored Names" list **Atom** > **Preferences** > **Settings** > **Core Settings** > **Ignored Names**. Just add any file or directory to the list.

Important: to activate the **Ignored Names** list setting, so Atom ignores the files you configured, ensure that **Hide Ignored Names** is enabled under menu **Atom** > **Preferences** > **Settings** > **Tree View** > **Hide Ignored Names**.

There are many ways to customize atom. Check out the official [Customizing Atom Page](https://atom.io/docs/latest/customizing-atom).

Comment: But it does not hide it from sidebar, it just disable the folder.

Comment: @Fizar Khan: this answer does hide it in the sidebar, but you also need to enable **Hide Ignored Names**  under menu **Atom** > **Preferences** > **Settings** > **Tree View** > **Hide Ignored Names**. I edited the answer to add the step to enable **Hide Ignored Names**.

Answer (score 20):

As stated above, Application menu > Preferences… > select Packages in the sidebar, search for "Tree View", click the Settings button > check Hide Ignored Names.

And now with pictures:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 20):

### just click on the `i` key in the tree view window

Click on the tree view from main window, type `i` on keyboard to toggle visibility of version control ignored files.

Comment: I suspect this is really the answer that most people are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all of the above info...

If you would like to hide all hidden files from the tree view:

- Go to the core settings page and under "Ignored Names" enter .*

This will hide all files starting with a .