# Missing application.yml file - Atom hiding vcs ignored files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, atom-editor, figaro-ruby

I am using Figaro to set up ENV variables. Ever since installing it, my `application.yml` has disappeared. When I do a search for the file in my editor, all that comes up is the reference to the file in my `secrets.yml` file to ignore `application.yml`. However, when I go to create a new `application.yml` in the config folder, it says that `application.yml` already exists.

I can see it in the finder as well.

I uninstalled Figaro and it still didn't come back, so now I'm not even quite sure it's absolutely connected to Figaro.

Any ideas? I'm happy to set up ENV variables manually, to try Enviable or another gem, but I'd like to find out what is causing this issue.

*This question has been edited to show that the problem is with Atom and not Figaro, please see Zhurora's answer.*

Comment: Have you simply checked it from the file system instead of just using your IDE?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question about 10 seconds after I posted it to indicate that I can see the file in finder. Not sure if you loaded this page before I edited it, but yes I can see the file in the file system. Still, I'm not sure how to make it available in my IDE.

Comment: I use Atom. I just downloaded Sublime Text to check it, and sure enough, I see application.yml in Sublime. I still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I guess you added `application.yml` into your `.gitignore` file? Atom hides those files by default. You have to look into Atom's settings:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727463/hide-hiddendot-files-in-github-atom-editor

Comment: @user2860664: Please update your question accordingly so that in future it can be seen that the problem probably lies in Atom instead of Figaro. Also, please let us know if the solution proposed by zhurora works or not.

Comment: @sanfor Thanks. I edited my question. Should be more helpful now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Atom: goto **Atom > Preferences > Packages > tree-view**, check **Hide VSC Ignored Files**. Atom hides files which are in your `.gitignore` by default.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much zhurora, that did indeed fix the problem.